# Footer won't center :S

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my footer. Darn footer always.
Anyway, it won't show up in the center of the page. I tried using `text-align:center` & `margin:auto` but it won't come off the left side.

I'm going to post the code here; maybe you can find the problem?

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
 <div class="footertxtl">
 </div>
   <div class="footertxtr">
   </div>
 <div class="designer">
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer {
    background-image:url(images/footer/footer.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
    height:223px;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;}

.footertxtl {
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    padding-left:60px;
    padding-top:165px;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;}

.designer {
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:205px;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;}

.footertxtr {
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    font-size:10px;
    padding-right:24%;
    padding-top:155px;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your footer is set to 100% width which means it will always fill the whole width of the body, unless it is contained within another div.

As a result, the footer is 100% width, with one div floating to the left, another to the right, and the other relative.

Give the `#footer` a fixed width, then give it `margin: 0 auto;` this will position this div in the center

Comment: Dude your awsome! Thank you so much. Works perfectly ;)
Have great day!

Comment: Cheers! (as we say in Scotland) :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example? If you have a container within your `#footer` which is not 100% wide, you can use `margin:0 auto;` to centre it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set constant width, then it is set by default to 100%. Your "width: auto" does not behave as you expected. If you do cannot set constant width and you do not mind about IE7, you could do like this:

```
   #footer{
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
   }
```

Remember about adding overflow: hidden; to parent div

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wrapper for the rest of the page that set's either a fixed width or a percentage (75%) then stick the footer inside the wrapper

```
<body style="text-align: center;">
 <div id="wrapper" style="text-align: left; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div id="Header">............</div>
  <div id="MainContent">.......</div>
  <div id="Footer">input content here</div>
 </div>
</body>
```

the wrapper will automatically center all of the content

```
#footer {
   background: transparent url(images/footer/footer.png) no-repeat left top;
   text-align:center;
   height:223px;
   clear:both;
}
```